# Download image from url and write text on it PHP

Tags: php, image, text, download

I want to download an image from url given by parameter and write some text on it (also from given text by parameter) here is my code but its not working(something like this: http://mr305.6te.net/img/wizard.php?img=http://www.phpforkids.com/images/php-for-kids-logo.gif?txt=ok)

```
<?php

  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_GET["img"]); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // good edit, thanks!
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); // also, this seems wise considering output is image.
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromstring($data);

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 14, 91);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'tahoma';


  $text = $_GET["txt"];


  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);


  imagejpeg($jpg_image, NULL, 75);


  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

Comment: Why does your code not work? Does it error - if so what's the error?

Comment: it doesn't show the text on image